# Angular - print element of JSON just once

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework

This is my code:

```
<ion-content padding>
  <h1>Datum: </h1> 
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let u of tecaj">
        <h2>{{u.datum}}</h2>
        <h2>{{u.drzava}} | {{u.valuta}}</h2>
        <p>{{u.srednji_tecaj}}</p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list> 
 </ion-content>
```

and I want to print date just once, so

```
<h2>{{u.datum}}</h2> just once in first <h1> after "Datum:"
```

on screenshot there is my JSON file. how do I take just one element of JSON object without *ngFor?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you extract the single element in the module and then bind single element?. Binding a single element from an array doesn't sound correct.

Comment: not sure how to do it? after I get JSON?

Comment: put your module code where you get your JSON. UI Isn't the right layer to filter your elements from an array unless otherwise, you give me a good reason doing so. What if array returns null?

Comment: those are my codes:
<pre>
getTecaj(valuta1, valuta2){
    return this.http.get(this.url+'?valuta='+valuta1+'&valuta='+valuta2)
    .map(res => res.json());
  }

this.hnbProvider.getTecaj(this.change.valuta1, this.change.valuta2).subscribe(tecaj => {
      console.log(tecaj);
     this.tecaj = tecaj;
    });<code>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Others have proposed good solutions, but the ngFor directive gives you access to several variables (index, first, last, odd and even) which allow even cleaner and more elegant code. So that means we can do the following:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let u of tecaj; let first = first">
    <h2 *ngIf="first">{{u.datum}}</h2>
```

Comment: I used this method, thanks! and this is the only one that worked from all the answers...

Answer (score 0):

You can change it as follows to access the `datum`, `drzava`, `valuta` and `srednji_tecaj` properties of the first element in the array:

```
<h1>Datum: </h1> 
<ion-item *ngIf="tecaj">
  <h2>{{ tecaj[0]?.datum }}</h2>
  <h2>{{ tecaj[0]?.drzava}} | {{ tecaj[0]?.valuta }}</h2>
  <p>{{ tecaj[0]?.srednji_tecaj }}</p>
</ion-item>
```

Everything inside interpolation (`{{}}`) will be evaluated and stringified and can then be rendered on the DOM.

Comment: it does not work :( I tried with tecaj[0].datum, 0.datum and [0].datum

Comment: Oh, did not know tecaj could be undefined, I updated my answer to account for that :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would say if you don't want to use for loop then I would go with David but I don't see any problem in using for loop and you can extract a single date by using the index in the loop as follows

```html
<ion-content padding>
  <h1>Datum: </h1> 
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let u of tecaj; index as i">
      <div *ngIf="i===0">
        <h2>{{u.datum}}</h2>
        <h2>{{u.drzava}} | {{u.valuta}}</h2>
        <p>{{u.srednji_tecaj}}</p>
       </div>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list> 
 </ion-content>
```